How to setup a repeatable job that only has one running instance
Is there a way to setup a repeatable job, that only ever has one running execution, when the setup has a worker concurrency of 1+.
I tried a repeatable job with debouncing.
  await queue.add('testjob, {}, {
    debounce: { id: 'testjob },
    repeat: { every: 2000 }
  })

What I was hoping for was that when the job was running, and if it takes longer than the repeat schedule, then the next job would debounce or skipped.
However, I see that new jobs are not created because of the debounce. In my setup, I use a value of 1000 for removeOnComplete, with one worker with 5 concurrency.
My goal is to setup a repeatable job with a frequency of 2 minutes, but if the job takes more than 2 minutes, then for the worker to wait for the first job to complete.
Is there a way to achieve the overall goal here?
